# Op Amp Circuit Gain Does not Match LTSpice Simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier

I created an amplifier in LTSpice as shown in the diagram and asc. file below. It is intended to accept a line level audio signal from a USB audio interface, and increase the voltage and current to drive a coil. The simulation indicates an output swing of about 0-9Vpp (blue trace). This is consistent with the parts and circuit topology. However, when constructed (twice from new parts), the circuit's gain only achieves half of that. IOW the output swings from 0V to only 4.5V, at which point it begins to clip if the gain is increased. I am aware that the offset and gain adjustments are interact, but I have tried all possible settings.

I am not sure what is happening. Judging by the sim plot, LTSpice wants to double whatever voltage I enter into V3. Maybe I am not using the correct analysis term? In the plot the 2.3V bipolar signal from the interface (green trace) is shown as reduced to 1.15V (purple) at pin 3 of the LM358.

1. Can anyone please help me understand why the built circuit's output voltage is low?
2. Why is this lack of gain not reflected in the simulation?

I posted on another forum but did not receive a detailed answer. I have re-edited it to make my question as clear as I can, in the hope someone can point me to the mistake.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the input bias voltage at the input the same in both simulation and measurement? How about the output DC level?

Comment: Stack, (1) I don't trust the 1 uH coil value for one thing. What is really being driven with the circuit you built?  (2) Your driver can pull up hard because of the Darlington, but it cannot pull down hard because there are no active devices to achieve that. (...) And there are other thoughts. But until those two are addressed, they don't matter. I also notice that you've cut off some of the chart and are using default node labels. It would help a lot if you would label your nodes on the schematic. This is your question after all. Put as much effort into it as you feel able.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage you enter into the source in SPICE is the **peak** voltage, so the p-p will be double.

One would expect from the loading†  that the voltage at the non-inverting input would be about 1.54Vp-p with a 1.15V peak input. That appears to be exactly what the simulation shows.

So there are no inconsistencies that I can see in the simulation and there is no way to know why your built circuit appears to differ. It could be a bad batch of parts or it could be experimental error with your test instruments or something else entirely- you have simply provided no information to go on.

† calculate the voltage divider result to confirm this for yourself

Comment: The Community bot is asking for more information, but I do not know what else to provide. The topic will probably be closed.Thank you for clarifying the peak voltage. The circuit's DC levels are consistent with the sim. The load is accurately represented. It is a wide area air core coil. I will try another batch of LM358's (not from Asia) and borrow another scope. Until then I will not be adding to this topic. Thanks to all for the input.